# Use Wait Cursor on web during post/get in WEB app

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've got a long stored procedure and I would like to let people know that yes indeed the app is working on it...

Long story short my telerik ajax manager doesn't fire the wait cursor until, the server is done. I then get a second of wait cursor while a few thousand records are painted and we're back to default with the ajax manager request end event.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You could use an overlay popup instead with some progress indicator.

Comment: i like it, load panel here I come!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out,

```
    function setBusy() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
    }

    function setDefault() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    }
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(setDefault);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(setBusy);
```

works like a charm!